# Random, Non-Repeating 2D List Python

Tags: python, list, numpy, random

I have a program that generates a two dimensional list containing a set number of 2 dimensional co-ordinates within a certain range. (It doesn't matter if the nested are lists or tuples) eg:

```
[[5, 0], [4, 6], [9, 7], [2, 9], [2, 6]]
```

The problem is that I wish for no two sublists to be equal while keeping the length of the outer list the same.

i have tried using random.sample:

```
pointx = random.sample(range(10),5)
pointy = random.sample(range(20),5)
points = list(zip(pointx,pointy))
```

where 10 is the x range, 20 is the y range and 5 is the amount of points:

```
[(1,0),(9,19),(8,13),(3,5),(0,14)]
```

However this method's maximum amount of points is only 10+20 where it clearly should be 10*20 because of the separate sample lists.

While writing this, i have realised that:

```
point2D = []
point1D = random.sample(range(10*20),5)
[point2D.append(divmod(i,10)) for i in point1D]
```

This is a viable approach, but also clumsy, i was wondering whether there was a better solve possibly involving numpy.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The above method's maximum number of points is 155 not 200 or 30. For the first `x` there are 20 possible `y`s, then for the second `x` there are `19` possible `y`s, etc. until you get `20 + 19 + ... + 11 = 155`.

Comment: So, did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a `2D` grid of shape `(10,20)` with points at each integer points. Now, let's say we want to select `5` unique points on this grid. That's all! We translate this to NumPy.

Choose `5` unique indices from all possible `200` indices with :

```
idx = np.random.choice(200, size=5, replace=0)
```

Convert these indices into `x` and `y` coordinates that is speaking in terms of matrices terminology, get the row and column indices :

```
row, col = np.unravel_index(idx,(10,20))
```

These would be the desired tuples.

Let's put these two steps together for a complete code -

```
idx = np.random.choice(200, size=5, replace=0)
out = np.column_stack((np.unravel_index(idx,(10,20))))
```

Let's use a sample case -

```
In [461]: idx = np.random.choice(200, size=5, replace=0)
     ...: out = np.column_stack((np.unravel_index(idx,(10,20))))
     ...: 

In [462]: out
Out[462]: 
array([[ 6, 18],
       [ 9, 17],
       [ 5,  7],
       [ 8,  2],
       [ 6, 12]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy we can create all of the ordered pairs of (x,y) and then randomly select a number of pairs.

```
# first create an array of all possible pairs from (0,0) to (9,19)
pairs = np.dstack(np.meshgrid(np.arange(10), np.arange(20))).reshape(-1,2)

# now select a random set of 25 of those pairs, which are unique
pairs[np.random.choice(np.arange(pairs.shape[0]), size=25, replace=False)]
```